# Disable Google Chrome Automatic Updates (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, updates, google-chrome, chromium

I have Google Chrome running in Full Screen Kiosk (FKI, --fki) mode for display purposes and don't want automatic updates because its on an offline system. I have removed the apt sources list `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome` and updated `/etc/default/google-chrome`:

```
repo_add_once="false"
repo_reenable_on_distupgrade="false"
```

and I am still getting "**Cant update chrome**" pop-up.

[image]

I have tried this without any luck: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9052345?hl=en

Can anyone suggest a method to disable chrome from ***even trying*** to update itself?

Comment: That popup is coming from Chrome, not apt, not Ubuntu. If the instructions to disable auto-update aren't working, file a bug with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have decided to ditch Google Chrome and start using Chromium instead.